# Magento Internal server error while importing large file

Tags: php, magento, memory, file-upload, memory-limit

I have a site built in magento.In the admin panel I have written a custom script to import products.For now I am uploading upto 500 products at a time. This process also includes importing images from diff websites.

Now I am facing the `internal server error 500` while importing the file. As it is a big file it takes 30-40 mins to run. I have increased all the settings from php.ini

```
max_execution_time to 6000
memory_limit to 1024M
upload_max_size 1000M
post_max_size 1000
```

What setting I am missing. If I am crossing memory limit. Is there way to clear memory. I have also unset the variables from my code for each loop.

Answer (score 1):

you can use MAGMI for import of products http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/. I have used this script to import 20,000 products plus there images from remote site. The performance and accuracy was really good.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing the following settings:

```
file_uploads On
upload_max_filesize 1000M
max_input_time 100000
session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
```

This one should have "M" in the end:

`post_max_size 1000M`

Also, did you intentionally put `to` here ?

```
memory_limit to 1024M
max_execution_time to 6000
```

It shouldn't be there.

Comment: Yes to is not in php.ini Here is what my ini file consists max_execution_time = 6000    
max_input_time = 100000 
memory_limit = 2048M     
post_max_size = 1000M
upload_max_filesize = 1000M
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440

Comment: Having these settings should be enough to be able to complete your import. Probably, it doesn't have anything to do with php.ini then. Check out the links others has posted ;)